# Restrict duplicate entries while inserting in core data using magical records

Tags: ios, swift3, magicalrecord

I saw some post related to this topic but nothing comes handy for me in this case. I am using [Magical Records](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) for storing data. Data is saving fine for the first time as I map it after coming from server.

```
  class func fnsConversationmapper(conversationJson: [JSON]) -> [Conversation] {

        var conversationArray = [Conversation]()
        for conversationDict in conversationJson {
            print(conversationDict)
//            let check = Conversation.mr_find(byAttribute: "id", withValue: conversationDict["id"].stringValue)
            let check = Conversation.mr_findFirst(byAttribute: "id", withValue: conversationDict["id"].stringValue)

            let conversationObj = Conversation.mr_createEntity()
            conversationObj?.name = conversationDict["name"].stringValue
            conversationObj?.id = conversationDict["id"].stringValue
            conversationObj?.image =  conversationDict["avatar"].stringValue
            conversationObj?.type = conversationDict["type"].stringValue
            conversationObj?.role = conversationDict["postedBy"]["role"]["name"].stringValue
            conversationObj?.postedOn = (conversationDict["postedOn"].stringValue).dateFromString() as NSDate?

            conversationArray.append(conversationObj!)
            if check == nil {
                NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default().mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
            }

            print("Saved data", Conversation.mr_findAll()!)

        }
         return conversationArray


}
```

I also have a `check` to see if the record is already present in db, but somehow when I again run the app from certain scenario (coming back and forth from some screens), entries get doubled in db. I am not understanding how this is happening. Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to write code in mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait() method that this record in already save with conversationObj?.id if exist then no need to save otherwise save........

Comment: do i have to use mr_saveToPersistentStore(completion: { (isSuccess, err)  method ??